# IE8 video alignment issue with videojs

Tags: css, html, video, modernizr

I'm using videojs to put a bunch of videos on a page and I can't figure out what is causing the first and third video to not have any margin between them like the rest of the videos do

http://appliedcodingtech.com/site/paper_handling_systems_automation_videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

1. Give all videos a class of `.left;` instead of alternating between `.left` and `.right`.
2. On the very first video replace `.marginB` with `.clearL` .
3. Add the css rule to your main style sheet:

   ```
   .video-js-box.left.clearL{
       margin: 0 10px 0 0;
   }
   ```

**Option 2**

Ok what you need to do is keep your alternate naming scheme i.e. `.left` and `.right`. On all of your `.left` divs replace `.clearL` with `.clearB`.

That should solve your problem and then you don't need to worry about adding in the extra css rule etc.

Comment: I added clearL and that didn't fix it. I don't want to remove the margin from .video-js-box, because that is the css from the plugin and if the rest of the videos have margin between them without removing that line, I would guess the rest of them should too.

Comment: I still have a problem with that same video after doing all of your steps. It's strange because it's not like that on this page - http://appliedcodingtech.com/site/coding_and_labeling_videos

Comment: @catfish: Are you sure you did it right? I tested it in IE8 and it worked perfectly. Could you update the code on your site so I can check. I am also looking into the other page now.

Comment: Oh crap I had missed one of the .right's. I changed it to a .left and it works like a charm now. Thanks alot man!

Comment: @catfish: No worries. Also if you check my answer now, I have an alternate solution for you which matches the other page. But either should work :)